# Cleaning up mutable array code

Tags: arrays, haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm trying to solve the MINFREE problem in "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design" using mutable arrays. The problem is as follows: given a list of `n` natural numbers, find the smallest natural number that does not appear in the list. I'm pretty sure that the following is a solution:

```
minFree2 :: [Int] -> Int
minFree2 ns =  (fromMaybe 0 $ elemIndex True seen)
  where
    bound = (1, length ns)
    seen = elems $ runSTArray $ do
      arr <- newSTArray bound False
      mapM_ (\n -> writeArray arr n False) ns
      return arr
```

But the `do` block looks awfully imperative to me, and I'd like to simplify it to a more functional style in order to get a better grasp on monads.

I can get as far as the following (rewriting only the `where` clause):

```
 bound = (1, length ns)
 setTrues arr = mapM_ (flip (writeArray arr) False) ns
 seen = elems $ runSTArray $ newSTArray bound False >>= setTrues
```

But that doesn't work, because it returns `()` rather than `STArray s i e`. I'd like to write something like:

```
    setTrues arr = mapM_ (flip (writeArray arr) False) ns >> arr
```

the same way I might write `fn arr => map ....; arr` in SML, but that doesn't work here because `arr` is an `STArray s i e` rather than a `ST s (STarray s i e)`. I'd expect to be able to fix that by wrapping `arr` back up in an `ST`, but my attempt with:

```
    setTrues arr = mapM_ (flip (writeArray arr) False) ns >> arr
    seen = elems $ runSTArray $ newSTArray bound False >>= return . setTrues
```

Yields the error:

```
No instance for (MArray (STArray s) Bool (STArray s Int))
  arising from a use of `setTrues'
```

which I don't entirely understand.

Is there a nice way to write this code, minimizing the use of `do`?

Comment: Note that this is the example in chapter 1 of [Richard Bird's Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521513383), and his results show that a divide-and-conquer approach using pure structures beats an `accumArray` based approach.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
setTrues arr = mapM_ (flip (writeArray arr) False) ns >> return arr
seen = elems $ runSTArray $ newSTArray bound False >>= setTrues
```

The trick is letting `setTrues` return the array instead of `()`, as you already attempted.

Comment: Whoops. I feel a bit silly having overlooked that. The `Control.Applicative` solution is much cleaner, though -- thanks for pointing that out. I'd be extra happy if `setTrues` could be rewritten to be point-free, but I suspect that can't be done sanely.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `<*` does the trick -- I get `Couldn't match expected type `ST s b0' with actual type `a0 Int Bool -> m0 ()'` --- `setTrues` isn't passed the STArray as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, one of the main purposes of the ST monad is to provide a loophole to imperative programming in purely functional code. So I guess, there is no nice solution using the ST monad which doesn't look too imperative. However, to get rid of the imperative style you could use the function

```
accumArray :: Ix i => (e -> a -> e) -> e -> (i, i) -> [(i, a)] -> Array i e
```

from `Data.Array`. In fact, the actual implementation of this function looks somewhat similar to your code.

Altogether, a more functional solution could look as follows:

```
minFree2 :: [Int] -> Int
minFree2 ns = fromMaybe 0 $ elemIndex False $ elems seen
  where
    bound = (1, length ns)
    seen :: Array Int Bool
    seen = accumArray (||) False bound $ map (,True) ns
```

PS: `True` and `False` seemed to be distributed slightly wrong. I silently fixed this.

Comment: This is a better solution, but I'm interested in one using mutable arrays for my purpose here -- I have a reference solution with an `accumArray` that I'm comparing against. Perhaps, though, the ugliness of ST is inevitable.